# L1-norm vs l2-norm as cost function when standardizing

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, gradient-descent

I have some data where both the input and the output values are standardized, so the difference between Y and Y_pred is always gonna very small.

I feel that the l2-norm will penalize less the model than the l1-norm since squaring a number that is between 0 and 1 will always result in a lower number.

So my question is, is it ok to use the l2-norm when both the input and the output are standardized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter.

The basic idea/motivation is how to penalize deviations. L1-norm does not care much about outliers, while L2-norm penalize these heavily. This is the basic difference and you will find a lot of pros and cons, even on wikipedia.

So in regards to your question if it makes sense when the expected deviations are small: sure, it behaves the same.

Let's make an example:

```
y_real 1.0      ||| y_pred 0.8     ||| y_pred 0.6 
l1:                |0.2| = 0.2         |0.4| = 0.4  => 2x times more error!
l2:                0.2^2 = 0.04        0.4^2 = 0.16 => 4x times more error!
```

You see, the basic idea still applies!

Comment: thanks for the reply. If we use the L2-norm, then as the error is lower, at each iteration of the gradient descent, the weights will only get corrected very lightly. So then, it should take more training iterations to converge to the optimal weights no?

Comment: It's not really only about the gradient-size of one weight. It's more about the joint-gradients. It's kind of thinking in a local (only this weight) vs. global (how do all these weight together behave) setting. Further more: learning-rate tuning is always important! So the general answer (there is much more to talk about; but it's too complex to discuss this on SO; smoothness and co.) is: it depends on the problem.

Comment: @sascha Don't you think your explanation is wrong? L2 doesn't penalize outliers as much as L1. In your example, L1 penalizes y=0.6 prediction as 0.4 which is much greater than 0.16 penalty by L2 norm.

Comment: @RaghavendraSS Don't compare the value of 0.4 with 0.16 (inter-model comparison). Compare the growth in penalization (intra-model comparison). While l1 want's to push the predictor to predict 0.8 instead of 0.6, l2 is pushing much stronger (a factor of 4 between these two errors; while l1 only has 2x)

Comment: @sascha But the cost matters, right ? Not the rate.Also by your analogy, L2 will penalize an outlier heavily and in turn model will try to fit that outlier. In that case, Model will perform poorly bec it's trying the fit an outlier.

Comment: Yes, l2 will try to fit any outlier stronger than l1 (at the cost of worse results for non-outliers). That's what's expected.